# Python - How to deal with webservice when not accessible?

Tags: python, web-services, try-catch, try-except

I'm coding some Python that will handle a call to an webservice.

```
def calculate(self):
    market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
    market_supply_price_usd = market_supply_price.get('usd')
    market_supply_price_eur = market_supply_price.get('eur')
    amount = '%.8f' % ((self.euro - ((self.euro*self.__tax_to_apply())+self.__extra_tax_to_apply())) / market_supply_price_eur)
    return {'usd': [market_supply_price_usd, amount], 'eur': [market_supply_price_eur, amount]}
```

The call to the webservice is on this line:

```
market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
```

This private method does various calls to the webservice and give me back a result. My problem here is that this webservice fails a lot. I need to implement a way that if the one of the calls fail I will wait for example 10 minutes and try again, if after 10 minutes fails again, I will wait 30 minutes and try again, if after 30 minutes fails again, I will wait 60 minutes...

What is the best possible way to implement something like this in the calculate() method?

I've implemented something like this but it looks wrong and not the way that should be done.

```
def calculate(self):
    try:
        market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
    except:
        pass
        try:
            time.sleep(600)
            market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
        except:
            pass
            try:
                time.sleep(600)
                market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
            except:
                pass
                try:
                    time.sleep(1200)
                    market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
                except:
                    sys.exit(1)
    market_supply_price_usd = market_supply_price.get('usd')
    market_supply_price_eur = market_supply_price.get('eur')
    amount = '%.8f' % ((self.euro - ((self.euro*self.__tax_to_apply())+self.__extra_tax_to_apply())) / market_supply_price_eur)
    return {'usd': [market_supply_price_usd, amount], 'eur': [market_supply_price_eur, amount]}
```

Any clues on how to do this the right way?

Best Regards,

Comment: Consider .. loops *if* you are gonna keep polling and crossing fingers. Whenever a pattern repeats more than 2-3 times, red flags should be raised. To make the code simpler, I'd put the code to read `market_supply_price` into it's own function, so that `return` can be used immediately on success - and then at that point it can be seen how such a poll is "somewhat generic". However, my *first* inclination would be to: ensure the web-service *is accessible*, or fail with it (log the failure and restart the entire process later). Otherwise the code is just covering up a larger problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply user2864740. I see your view on it. I will try to handle the problem by let it fail, log it and later restart again. Thanks.

Comment: consider using a seperate thread or process to poll the results from the web service and store them in e.g. a database. Instead of nesting your try except blocks in several layers, just use a variable for the time the thread is going to sleep and increment it up to a certain level, e.g. 1 hr.

Answer (score 0):

Loops work well for this type of thing. Here's an example where you specify timeouts:

```
def calculate(self):
    for timeout in (600, 600, 1200):
        try:
            market_supply_price = self.__price_to_pay_current_market_supply()
            break
        except: # BAD! Catch specific exceptions
            sleep(timeout)
    else:
        print "operation failed"
        sys.exit(1)

    market_supply_price_usd = market_supply_price.get('usd')
    market_supply_price_eur = market_supply_price.get('eur')
    etc...
```